# How to reset table id 1 without using table truncate

Tags: sql-server

> How to start table primary key and identity Id from 1 without using
>   table truncate in Sql-Server.

Comment: Why do you care? It doesn't matter to the database and primary key values should seldom be exposed to the front end so only the developer is going to see it(and they shouldn t care either)

Comment: why you don't used truncate, you need data from it?

Comment: If you care at all about the numeric value of identity columns, I'd suggest you're using them wrong. You should treat them as opaque blobs that *happen* to fit in numeric columns/data types.

Answer (score 1):

There is a console command that will do this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql

`DBCC CHECKIDENT`

Answer (score 0):

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 1);